# Програмирование Telit

Tags: python

Встала задача работать с telit. там используется python. Но как заливать этот код,как смотреть результат? Есть какие-то мануалы,примеры,инструкции? Перерыл весь интернет-толкового ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, материалов вроде вполне хватает:

- [TELIT PYTHON START GUIDE](https://www.roundsolutions.com/media/pdf/TER-EZ910V4-HAUPT_Telit_Python_Start_Guide_r0.pdf) – здесь есть всё необходимое.
- [Telit: Python Equipped](https://www.telit.com/technical-forum/families-of-modules/python-equipped/) – вопросы-ответы на оффициальном сайте.
- [Хабр: Пишем первую простую прошивку для Telit](https://habr.com/post/153009/) – даже на русском есть некоторые пояснения.